# Wavesurfer.js doesn't work with Vue component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, wavesurfer.js

I want to use **wavesurfer.js** to make a visual audio player component. But it doesn't work with Vue.

**Player.vue:**

```
<template>
  <div><div id="wave"></div></div>
</template>

<script>
  import WaveSurfer from "wavesurfer.js";

  export default {
    name: "Player",
    mounted() {
      this.wavesurfer = WaveSurfer.create({
        container: "#wave"
      });
      this.wavesurfer.load("../media/song.mp3");
      this.wavesurfer.on("ready", function() {
        this.wavesurfer.play();
      });
    }
  };
</script>
```

There is an error message on console:

[image: error-console]

A blank area is rendered in the page:

[image: blank-area]

I try to catch error like this.

```
  mounted() {
    try {
      this.wavesurfer = WaveSurfer.create({
        container: "#wave"
      });
      this.wavesurfer.load("../media/song .ogg");
      this.wavesurfer.on("ready", function() {
        this.wavesurfer.play();
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
```

But it doesn't catch any error. Console is the same as before.

Comment: Are you sure this line is working "this.wavesurfer.load("../media/song.mp3");"? If you tried with an external mp3 song does it work? I tested your code and it is working https://codepen.io/aquilesb/pen/eboZYe

Comment: Can you post the full error exception? . Use try...catch for this. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMException 
My guess is that the mp3 file is not found. The file path is wrong.

Comment: I try to catch exception like this, but it doesn't catch any error.   `  mounted() {
    try {
      this.wavesurfer = WaveSurfer.create({
        container: "#wave"
      });
      this.wavesurfer.load("../media/song .mp3");
      this.wavesurfer.on("ready", function() {
        this.wavesurfer.play();
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
`

Comment: I also think there's a problem with the file path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is wrong with the file path. After I tried with an external mp3 song, it worked correctly.

```
this.wavesurfer.load("http://localhost:3000/public/song.mp3");
```